# Perl Selenium webdriver button click not working

Tags: html, perl, selenium

The script is able to click login button and that works.  After logging in, if there is another user logged in there is an option to force out the logged in user.

Here's the button...

```
<span id="Pages_DiagnosticsForceout_btnForceout" class="yui-button yui-push-button">
<span class="first-child">
<button type="button" tabindex="0">Force‌·Log‌·Out</button>
</span>
</span>
```

Here is the attempted click... adding more info not entire script.

```
#!/root/localperl/bin/perl5.22.0

use warnings;
use strict;

use Selenium::Firefox;
use Selenium::Firefox::Profile;
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;
use Selenium::Waiter;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;
use Config;
use YAML;

my $ff;

logit("Attempting create profile ");

my $start = getTime();
my $profile;
my $profObject = wait_until { $profile = Selenium::Firefox::Profile->new; };

if ($profObject) {

    my $createProfile = wait_until { $profile->{profile_dir} = $ARGV[3]; };

    if ($createProfile) {
        logit("profile created, attempting browser start ");
    }
    else {
        logit("profile create failed");
        exit;
    }
}
else {
    logit("create profile object failed");
}

my $browser = wait_until {
    $ff = Selenium::Firefox->new(
        'default_finder'  => 'id',
        'firefox_profile' => $profile
    );
};

'''

my $forceOutButton = wait_until {
    $ff->find_element_by_xpath(".//*[\@id='Pages_DiagnosticsForceout_btnForceout']/span/button")->click();
};
```

Using firepath in firebug the xpath looks like it is selecting the button.  Yet the button is not clicked.  I set it up to never timeout so its not a timeout problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you realise what [`Selenium::Waiter`](http://metacpan.org/module/Selenium::Waiter) actually does. Its documentation doesn't help much and its name doesn't either as it's nothing really to do with Selenium

Basically `wait_until { ... }` keeps calling the code in the block once a second for thirty seconds (those values are defaults and can be changed in parameters to the call) or until it returns a *true* value

That means that many of your `wait_until` calls are unnecessary. For instance

```
$profile = Selenium::Firefox::Profile->new
```

will return pretty swiftly with a new object. There is no point retrying the `new` until it works

Similarly, there is *certainly* no point in waiting for this statement

```
$profile->{profile_dir} = $ARGV[3]
```

as it is just a simple assignment and will execute instantaneously. However, if `$ARGV[0]` happens to have a *false* value then `wait_until` will keep doing the assignment thirty times and then give up

I presume that the module is intended to wait for structures in the page to be created by JavaScript, and if your *force log out* button is created this way then it may be sensible to use `wait_until` to check whether it has been created. However you shouldn't call `click` inside the wait, you should just keep checking whether the XPath expression can be found

Something like this perhaps

```
my $force_out_button = wait_until {
    $ff->find_element_by_xpath('//span[@id="Pages_DiagnosticsForceout_btnForceout"]/span/button')
};

die "Force log out button not found" unless $force_out_button;

$force_out_button->click;
```

Note that, because of the way you've been using `wait_until` and assigning a variable inside the block as well as outside, you have two names for a couple of things. For instance `$ff` and `$browser` are the same thing, and `$profObject` is the same as `$profile`. I've chosen to keep only `$ff` and `$profile here

Also, this line

```
my $createProfile = wait_until { $profile->{profile_dir} = $ARGV[3]; };
```

simply copies `$ARGV[3]` to both `$profile->{profile_dir}` and `$createProfile`. You're not "creating" anything, like your log message implies, and the only reason this can fail is if `$ARGV[3]` is a *false* value

The part of your program program that you have shown should look more like this

```
#!/root/localperl/bin/perl5.22.0

use strict;
use warnings;

use Selenium::Firefox;
use Selenium::Firefox::Profile;
use Selenium::Remote::WDKeys;
use Selenium::Waiter;
use Data::Dumper;
use Time::Piece;
use Config;
use YAML;

logit("Attempting to create profile");

my $start = getTime();

my $profile = Selenium::Firefox::Profile->new;

unless ($profile) {
    logit("Create profile object failed");
    exit 1;
}

unless ( $ARGV[3] and -d $ARGV[3] ) {
    logit("Profile create failed - invalid profile dir");
    exit 1;
}

$profile->{profile_dir} = $ARGV[3];
logit("Profile created, attempting browser start");

my $ff = Selenium::Firefox->new(
    default_finder  => 'id',
    firefox_profile => $profile
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  the reason for wrapping a lot of stuff in wait_until is for testing.  I was struggling with profiles and browser start.  I'll clean it up for delivery. The ff and browser object are in different scopes.  I'll look into making it more consistent.  Inherited code.  I've used the click in other wait_until and they are working.  I was thinking the button was not being found but couldn't verify.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked.  I discovered two fields the button need weren't populated when the button clicked.  I'm now waiting on those fields to populate before looking for the button.  My click method didn't allow me to see those fields.  Thanks again.  You made my day.

Comment: @dean: I'm pleased it helped. Add the `click` to the statement inside the `wait_until` will change it from simply verifying whether the HTML element exists to calling `click` on an undefined value and having `wait_until` rescue your program from a fatal `Can't call method "click" on an undefined value` error. I hope you can see that it's cleaner if you move the `click` outside the wait

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what manner of thing `$ff` is, but in

```
my $forceOutButton = wait_until {$ff->find_element_by_xpath(".//*[\@id='Pages_DiagnosticsForceout_btnForceout']/span/button")->click();};
```

I'm pretty sure the opening brace in `wait_until {` should be an opening parenthesis, as otherwise you're passing `wait until` a reference to a hash with the button as the key and `undef` as the value

I would write this as

```
my $btn = $ff->find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Pages_DiagnosticsForceout_btnForceout"]/span/button');

my $forceOutButton = wait_until( $btn->click() );
```

Even that looks very wrong to me, but at least you can check whether the button is being found

If you reveal more of your code, in particular what modules you're using, then I'm sure we can help you better

Comment: I'm guessing the OP is using [Selenium::Waiter::wait_until](https://metacpan.org/pod/Selenium::Waiter#wait_until), which takes a block as the first argument. They'll have to clarify, though.

Comment: sorry, that is the remote driver object my $ff = newBrowser();

Comment: yes, I am using  Selenium::Waiter.  I added the modules and other code chunks